# Is it possible for a completion $\hat R$ to be finitely generated over $R$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a local Noetherian ring. Denote by $\hat R$ the $m$-adic completion of $R$. Is the following statement correct?

If $\hat R$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $R=\hat R$.

Comment: Yes, as $\hat{R}$ is $R$-flat module and $\hat{E} = \hat{R}\otimes_R E$ where $\hat{E}$ is $m$-adic completion of finitely generated module $E.$ Consider exact $R$-sequence $R\to\hat{R}\to \hat{R}/R.$

Comment: @dsh What does that have to do with finite generation of $\hat{R}$? All the statements in your comment hold for any Noetherian ring $R$

Comment: @math5432,If $\hat{R}$ is not finitely generated, then $\hat{R} \otimes \hat{R} = \hat{R}$ does not follow.

Comment: $\hat{R}$ is *faithfully* $R$-flat module in this case.

Comment: @dsh I see your point - the isomorphism $\hat{E} \cong \hat{R} \otimes_R E$ only holds when $E$ is finitely generated. Now a finitely generated flat module over a Noetherian local ring is actually free, so $\hat{R} \otimes \hat{R} \cong \hat{\hat{R}} \cong \hat{R} \implies \hat{R} \cong R$

Comment: @math54321. Reasoning using finitely generated modules over local rings seems  easier. From faithfully flat $\hat{R}$ one can derive $\hat{R}\otimes_R (\hat{R}/R) = 0$ and $\hat{R}/R = 0$

Comment: @dsh perhaps, you can combine your comments into an answer. I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference: Bourbaki, "Commutative algebra, ch II, III."

1. $\hat{R}$ is faithfully flat $R$-module.
2. $\hat{E} = \hat{R}\otimes_R E$ for finitely generated $R$-module $E.$
3. From exact sequence of finitely generated $R$-modules
   $$
   R\to\hat{R}\to\hat{R}/R
   $$
   one derives exact sequence ($\hat{R}$ is flat)
   $$
   \hat{R}\to\hat{\hat{R}}=\hat{R}\to\hat{R}/R \otimes_R \hat{R}
   $$
4. $\hat{R}/R \otimes_R \hat{R} = 0,$ because first arrow maps 1 to 1.
5. $\hat{R}$ is $R$-faithful, then $\hat{R}/R = 0.$